# Octobercms: Polymorphic relationship error

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am trying to create a Add to favourite function where a user can add many adverts to a favourite list and an advert can be added by many users.

My database structure looks like this

```
user
-id
-name
...
```

```
advert
-id
-title
...
```

```
favourites
-user_id
-favourite_id
-favourite_type
-created_at
-updated at
```

My model relationship

User Model Extended

```
  User::extend(function($model){
        $model->morphedByMany['adverts'] = ['Corymillz\Adverts\Models\Advert', 'name' => 'favourite', 'withPivot' => ['çreated_at'], 'orderBy'  => 'pivot_created_at desc'];

         });
```

Advert Model Extended

```
 public $morphToMany = [
        'users' => [

        'RainLab\User\Models\User',
        'name' => 'favourite',
       ]

        ];
```

I created a page and tried to test it retrieving records

```
<?php
use Corymillz\Adverts\Models\Advert;


function onStart(){

$ads = Advert::find(1); 

dd($ads->users);

}

?>
```

but i am getting this error

> Trying to get property 'users' of non-object

Any reason why or is something wrong with my setup?

Comment: could you display what dd($ads) returns ?

Comment: it came up with ````null````

Comment: This means Advert::find(1) returns no data. This is why $ads is a non-Object and you have this error accessing to user.
You probably do not have advert with id 1 in your database